# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'End' and no accessible extension method 'End'

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am using Range.End to get the content on a cell from an excel, like this:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

lastRow = sheetExcel.Cells[sheetExcel.Rows.Count, "A"].End[XlDirection.xlUp].Row;
```

However, the directive  does not seem to recognize the Range.End

I've tried `get_End` and it doesn't work either.

I get the same issue when trying to use `ColumnWidht`  `Interior.Color` or anything like that, it always has to do with the reference/directive not recognizing it.

Comment: It seems that `sheetExcel.Cells[sheetExcel.Rows.Count, "A"]` is giving you an `object`. What type is `sheetExcel` here?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama It's (local variable) _Worksheet

Comment: So `.Cells` is a `Range`, and the [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.item?view=excel-pia#microsoft-office-interop-excel-range-item(system-object-system-object)) accepts a `RowIndex` and a `ColumnIndex` and returns an `object`. Are you sure `.End` is valid for the result?